# Pyinstaller unable to find renderer plugin for opengl

Tags: python, qml, pyinstaller, pyside2, qt3d

I developed an application using Qml and Python. This application uses the Qt3D module of Qml for the 3D rendering of .stl files. This application works fine when running in python But the problem is that when I create an executable file by using Pyinstaller it shows the following error after running the created .exe file:

```
Unable to find renderer plugin for opengl
```

Does anyone know why the application exe file doesn't start due to this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. The approach is to copy manually the folder:

```
E:\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\PySide2\plugins\renderers
```

to the `.exe` file location. Moreover, I use the following versions:

- Python 3.7.4
- PySide2 5.15.2
- Pyinstaller 4.5.1